# what is wrong with sed while using words starting with "w"

Tags: shell-script, sed, escape-characters

This works

```
echo "         HELLO   x=10" |sed 's/ *\HELLO \+/HELLO /g'
```

removes continuous space before hello and after word "HELLO"

but this doesn't

```
echo "         WHERE     x=10" |sed 's/ *\WHERE \+/WHERE /g'
```

i have tried to escape \w with \w like below

```
echo "         WHERE     x=10" |sed 's/ *\\"WHERE" \+/\"WHERE" /g'
```

but even this is not working. 
What is wrong.

Comment: As the asker of the question, you can accept the answer that is most relevant and/helpful to you.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3):

Why are you escaping the H and the W ?

`\H` and `\W` have specific meanings, and they are different from `H` and `W` .

```
echo "         WHERE     x=10" |sed 's/ *WHERE \+/WHERE /g'
```

Comment: Thanks ,can't up vote , don't have that reputation

Comment: You may not  be able to upvote, but you can [accept one of these answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Just drop the `\` before the words.

```
echo "         WHERE     x=10" |sed 's/ *WHERE \+/WHERE /g'
WHERE x=10
```

The `\` in regular expressions is used as an escape character for various type of matches.

The `\w` is used to find a word character, i.e. a character from `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, including the `_` (underscore) character.

As an upper case version *negates* a match, your `\W` means *don't* match a single character, which obviously makes the regex *fail* for your input string.

Try for example:

```
echo "         {HERE     x=10" |sed 's/ *\WHERE \+/WHERE /g'
WHERE x=10
```

it works because `{` **is** matched by `\W` (as `{` is NOT a word character)!

Comment: Thanks ,can't upvote , don't have that reputation . actually \ worked with HELLO but not with WHERE and confused me.

Comment: @etl_devs that's because \h matches _whitespace_ and then \H _not whitespace_ which means the H in HERE gets matched